# ListView item with a button on it swallows touch events

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'm working on an android app in which I'm displaying a list of items and allowing the user to click on a star icon to favourite items, which will then be displayed in a separate activity.

For this list then I am using a RelativeLayout with a ImageView for an icon, a TextView for a name of the item and an Button for the favourite button.

The problem I have is that without the button the list items touch properly and glow on response to a touch. With the button however they dont glow correctly, however they will fire any methods I place in the android:onClick xml attribute of the relativeLayout

Does anyone know of a way to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

When using an ImageButton you have to call

```
myImageButton.setFocusable(false);
```

programmatically because its constructor sets it to true. You can do so by overwriting the getView-method of your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.findViewById(R.id.idOfYourImageButton).setFocusable(false);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set listview `focusable` to be `false`

Here are some similar problems

[Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

[Using a checkbox with a false focusable, still prevents listview clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114154/using-a-checkbox-with-a-false-focusable-still-prevents-listview-clicks)

and some more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+listview+focusable+false)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of stackoverflow questions on this, but none that seemed to give a simple solution, so I'm posting what worked for me here:

My specific example involves a ListFragment, each item in the listview contains a standard button. I want the button and the listview to be clickable separately.

In the listFragment, add this:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        this.getListView().setItemsCanFocus(false);
    }
```

In the xml for the row item, add this to the Button XML:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

.. and that's it. Did the trick for me.

Comment: does this still allow focusing through the trackball? Would prefer a solution that supports the trackball as many old phones are still in use with them.

Comment: Another small issue: clicking the row makes the button show it's pressed state, even though it registers `onListItemClick` on the row (and not `onClick` for the Button). Any solution for that?